# Why the builtin slice function doesn't throw an exception for impossible slicing conditions?

Tags: python

Why #python doesn't throw an exception for `slice` objects like this?

```py
>>> y = slice(10, 2, 5) # impossible condition
>>> y
slice(10, 2, 5)
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x[y] # applying the slice on an iterable
[]
>>>
```

The slice function should have thrown an exception because slice(start=10, stop=2, step=5) is an impossible condition. If you start at index 10, and take strides of 5, you will never reach index 2.

Yet, the slice function happily accepts that condition and keeps quiet (i.e. returns an empty slice). I am curious why that behavior was chosen for implementation of `slice`, given a Zen of python states "Errors should never be passed silently".

Comment: what is `y` there?

Comment: `slice(10,2,5)` is an empty slice, not an illegal one.

Comment: Hi @Netwave, y was the slice object. Edited the quoted code to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect [slice](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/slice) to be invalid if an empty `slice` is the result. However, `slice` behaves differently. You define your criteria when you call `slice` and the `result` is a slice object. The documentation says:

> slice() returns a slice object used to slice a sequence in the given
>   indices.

So empty slices are not considered to be exceptional cases, but rather cases when the `slice` object is empty.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Of course, the behavior is clear from observation and documentation. But I am curious why that behavior was chosen, given the Zen of python "Errors should never be passed silently". 
If you start at index 10, and take strides of 5, you will never reach index 2.

Comment: @AbdulMuneer because that's not considered to be an error. Think about set definitions. If you define a set which is empty, that's not a mathematical error whatsoever, unless you expect to have at least an element in your set. This is similar. You define a set, which is empty in your case. You can consider that to be an error, but on language level there is no context whatsoever about your specific problem to solve. So, if you want to consider this to be an error, then you will need to check whether your slice is empty and if so, handle it as an error.

Comment: @AbdulMuneer in my previous comment I have given a theoretical explanation. Now let's focus on practice. Let's assume that I intend to create a slice and do a loop based on that. In general, if my slice is empty, I am perfectly happy with the loop not doing anything and I would be unhappy to have to write a wrapper logic which would handle an empty slice as an exceptional case. It would be unintuitive and labor-intensive if I am to work with a lot of slices. Empty slice is not an error per se, because there is a perfectly valid explanation for empty sets.

Comment: @AbdulMuneer there is a lot to consider here. For example, some languages yield infinity when a division by zero occurs. Python throws an error. Both approaches hold water. Mathematically division by zero is infinity (if the number you divide differs from 0), so Javascript is right. However, the result is outside the bounds of real numbers, so Python is right as well. In this specific example one may argue as you did that an empty slice is an error. And it's understandable. Or one may argue that mathematically empty sets are not considered to be problematic at all.

Comment: @AbdulMuneer So, I think at the end of the day, when developers of such a technology face such a dilemma, where they could do multiple possible implementations and they can choose one, the practical point of view is a decisive factor.